# JSON.parse и одинарные кавычки

Tags: javascript, json

Есть способ заставить `JSON.parse()` понимать одинарные кавычки?

```
JSON.parse("{'id': 19}");
```

Из разметки приходит этот параметр, не хочется там экранировать или писать атрибут в одинарных типа:

```
data-params = '{"id": 19}'
```

Comment: В `Json` нет одинарных кавычек, сгенерируйте нормально вашу строку и не будет проблем, костыльным решением является замена всех одинарных на двойные.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сам формат JSON не предусматривает использование одинарных кавычек. `JSON.parse` в свою очередь ориентируется на [спецификацию `JSON`](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). Поэтому заставить понимать невалидный JSON нельзя.